# Changing a basis and satisfying inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem where I must have that $x, y, z \gt 0$, but I have also found that the solution lies on the plane spanned by the vectors:

$$\begin{pmatrix} -0.58 \\ 0.79 \\ -0.21 \end{pmatrix}r + \begin{pmatrix} -0.58 \\ -0.21 \\ 0.79 \end{pmatrix}s $$

Is there a way for me to express the positivity constraint on $x$, $y$, and $z$  in terms of $r$ and $s$? The way I did it was to put it into the form:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -0.58 && -0.58 \\ 0.79 && -0.21 \\ -0.21 && 0.79\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} r \\ s\end{pmatrix} \gt \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} $$  and row reduce, but that gives me funky answers... (mainly that $s \gt 0$ and $r \lt s$).

Comment: Row reduction does not preserve order...

Comment: Ah, I now realize you must be very careful with each step...